# Web app reconnect (socket.io) when phone wakes from sleep

Tags: android, node.js, mobile, socket.io, webbrowser-control

I've encountered a problem with socket.io...

I'm building a raspberry pi media player web app, using node.js and socket.io... I'm using my phone's browser as a remote controller... Everything works fine, the only problem is that if I don't use controller, the phone falls asleep and the socket disconnects. When I poke on the phone again, it takes random amount of seconds to reconnect to the server (more than 30). I need that reconnection instantly!

Part of my client code where I want to reconnect to the server is:

```
$('body').on('click',function(){
        if(socket.connected === false || socket.connected === undefined){
            socket = io.connect('http://' + utilities.localIPAdress + ':3000', {forceNew: true}); 
            console.log('Reconnecting to server');
            alert('Reconnecting to server');
        }
    });
```

Here I just want to check the connection when I tap on the phone's screen and reconnect if socket is disconnected. In matter of fact I want to create new connection, because I've also tried with socket.socket.reconnect(); and it didn't work at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to socket.io but this is what I'm using for pretty much the same problem (*raspberrypi-nodejs-socket.io-sleeping mobile browser*)

Try this:

```
var socket = io('http://' + utilities.localIPAdress + ':3000',
{'reconnection': true,'reconnectionDelay': 500,'maxReconnectionAttempts':Infinity}
);
```

This way you don't have to manually reconnect with the body-click, it's going to automagically try to reconnect indefinitely. I'm using a 500ms delay, not sure how it affects performance but play around with it and see what happens.

You can do something at each connection state like this:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

socket.on('reconnecting', function() {
    console.log('reconnecting'); 
});

socket.on('reconnect_error', function(obj) {
    console.log('reconnection error'); 
});     

socket.on('reconnect_failed', function() {
    console.log('reconnection failed');
});     

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnected');
});
```

Check out socket.io's site for more info:
http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I discover that `socket.io` don't know it is disconnected.
`disconnect` callback doesn't work. And `socket.connected` is still **true**.

I must disconnect socket first, and then connect it.

I also don't how to make app reconnect automatically.
I using a click button to reconnect it by person-self.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114169/socket-io-on-mobile-does-not-disconnect-on-device-sleep-close-browser-change)

Comment: This is not an answer. Please have look at [answer]